# Unique solution of linear system with pseudo inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

recently I have a linear system $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ to solve. Suppose $A^\dagger$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$. If $A$ is overdetermined, i.e. more rows than columns, then $\mathbf{x}=A^\dagger\mathbf{b}$ is the unique least squares solution. If $A$ is underdetermined, i.e. more columns than rows, though there are infinitely many solutions, then $\mathbf{x}=A^\dagger\mathbf{b}$ is the unique solution with minimum norm.

Is my understanding right? Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Details worked out in [Is the unique least norm solution to Ax=b the orthogonal projection of b onto R(A)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966893/is-the-unique-least-norm-solution-to-ax-b-is-the-orthogonal-projection-of-b-on/2181082#2181082).

The picture shows the uniqueness condition of a trivial nullspace $\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right).$
[image: The least squares minimizers are an affine space.]